# Retain filter and sorting on ngtable reload

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ngtable to display log details of from server. My table continuously gets updated but I want to retain the sorting and filter upon table reload. my ngtable code is as below.

```
          $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,
                    count: 5,
                    filter: {
                        message: ''
                    },
                    sorting: {
                        Id: 'asc'
                    }
                },
                {
                    getData: function($defer, params) {
                        var data = params.sorting() ?
                            $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                            $scope.data;

                        params.total(data.length);
                        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **$scope.tableParams.reload();** whenever you get updated data. This will retain all filters and sorting and will just reload the data.